# Реализация вывода новых заказов

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите плз. Есть задача на php никак не могу придумать как ее реализовать:
Вобщем Есть таблица с пользователями, пользователи делятся на две категирии Заказчик и Поставщик.
Заказчик создает заказ, у поставщиков отображается таблица с заказами. Нужно сделать так чтобы новый заказ был отмечен, допустим, другим цветом, при клике по этому заказу статус менялся на Просмотренно но только для текущего пользователя, для всех других он оставался в статусе не просмотрено.

Comment: И? Вы сами-то хоть что-то попытались сделать?

Comment: Единственное что приходит в голову это сделать в таблице заказов поле с id пользователей через запятую, и по мере просмотра удалять от туда id

Comment: Если мы о структуре таблиц в БД, то один заказ могут видеть много поставщиков и один поставщик может выполнять много заказов. Значит сущности относятся как много ко многим. Не трогая две первых таблицы, создаёте третью, куда помещаете id из обеих таблиц и возможно ещё какие-то поля. Именно в ней и будет веселье.

Comment: Виноват, у вас и заказчики, и поставщики хранятся в одной таблице, только это мы с вами про структуру БД говорим, а не про php.

Comment: Тоесть каждый раз при создании заказа в треью таблицу будут заноситься id поставщиков и id заказа и при просмотре конкретным пользователем его id будет удаляться из этой таблицы?

Comment: ну удаляться, а помечаться в доп. столбце как Просмотрено. возможно после осуществления заказа эти данные становятся неактуальными и их можно удалять

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать